# JS recursively check object fields (+nested) to be false/true

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have such an object:

```
const data = {
    name: 'somename',
    valid: true,
    childs: [{
        name: 'somename',
        valid: true
    }, {
        name: 'somename',
        valid: true,
        childs: [{
            name: 'somename',
            valid: true,
            childs: [{
                name: 'somename',
                valid: false
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

and I'm trying to figure out the best way to check if all `valid` keys values are set to true. My object is unpredictable by nested limit => so I think it's a good idea to recursion.

But I stuck:  if I will need to collect numbers or whatever else: it's easy to do, but how to be with true/false values?

I started so...

```
checkTrueFalse = (data) => {
    return ctrl.checkTrueFalseItems(data);
};

checkTrueFalseItems = (dataItem) => {
    return dataItem.filter(item => item.enabled).length === dataItem.length;
};
```

What's the best way to check if all `valid` fields of my data is set to true/false? In case all 'valid' fields are true => result should be true, if not => false.

Comment: What must be the output of such check? 'true' if all 'valid' are 'true'? or what?

Comment: If you are using recursion, why not just check the valid property on the current item on the current level?

Comment: @ygorbunkov In case all 'valid' fields are true => result should be true, if not => false.

Comment: @EricSvitok problem is that I stuck how to code it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple recursion loop over the childs is what you need to do. Using every() makes it easier to get the Boolean.

```js
const data = {
    name: 'somename',
    valid: true,
    childs: [{
        name: 'somename',
        valid: true
    }, {
        name: 'somename',
        valid: true,
        childs: [{
            name: 'somename',
            valid: true,
            childs: [{
                name: 'somename',
                valid: false
            }]
        }]
    }]
};

const checkIfAllTrue = obj => {
  return obj.valid && (!obj.childs || obj.childs.every(checkIfAllTrue))
}

console.log(checkIfAllTrue(data))
```